# Extract an int from a byte string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since a switch from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7 I encounter a lot of issues with my old code:

I have:

```
>>> print(o)
b' Avail\n113782\n'
>>> print(type(o))
<class 'bytes'>
```

I would like to extract only the number 113782.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply split it at the `\n` character:

```
>>> o.split(b'\n')
[b' Avail', b'113782', b'']
```

...and convert the second item to an integer:

```
>>> int(o.split(b'\n')[1])
113782
```

Make sure you also use a bytes object `b'\n'` for splitting, and not a string, `'\n'`, to avoid this error:

```
>>> o.split('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```